# Loading lots of images in Android

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-bitmap

I was trying to load lots of thumbnails into a GridView, but it ended up in an OutOfMemoryException. I want to load about 500-1000 (or even more) images into the GridView and I plan to use MINI_SIZE thumbnails. Now I'm asking what an ideal and low-performance approach to that would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load the images use a background thread like an `AsyncTask` and use a `Recyclerview` with a `GridLayoutManager`  that should load the images as you are dragging and not all at once

Answer (score 1):

This is where [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) comes into the picture.

What is a RecyclerView?

> It's like a ListView in which your android system will automatically recycle those views which are not visible on the screen anymore. It allows the user to scroll(vertically and horizontally) between the views and it maintains it's own cache. What `automatically recycling" means here is that it maintains a threshold of "not-anymore visible views" and then re-uses those views which have passed the threshold limit.

Hmm! But how will you load so many images, won't it cause an ANR?

There are two approaches to fix this problem:

1. Use RecyclerView's [Infinite/Endless Scrolling](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView) where it will load some percentage of images at first and when the user will scroll, it will automatically load more.
2. Use a `HandlerThread` or `AsyncTask` or simply a `Thread` to load all the items at once and show a `ProgressBar` until you are done loading. But this approach can cause `OOM (Out Of Memory)` in some devices.

Also, don't forget to use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for caching images.

Comment: That tipp about Glide made it work so well! Thank you so much!